# Проблемы с обработкой и отправкой media_group aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, async-await

```
async def collect_data_with_car(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
print('collect_data_with_car')
try:

    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['photo'] = message.photo[-1].file_id
        print(message.media_group_id)

        print(data)
        album.append({"media" : data['photo'], "type" : "photo"})
        print(album)


except:
    await message.reply("Прикрепи фото")
    dp.register_message_handler(collect_data_with_car, state=FSMAdd.collect_data_with_car)
finally:
    await bot.send_media_group(message.from_user.id, media=album)
    await FSMAdd.next()
```

Необходимо отправлять media_group в том же состоянии, в котором она и была отправлена.
Но данный код обрабатывает каждую фотографию отдельно и каждый раз отправляет media_group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

данный хендлер срабатывает на каждую фотографию. рекомендую использовать MediaGroupFilter, ссылка на документацию aiogram - https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters.html#aiogram.dispatcher.filters.MediaGroupFilter

Comment: Не очень понимаю каким образом мне поможет MediaGroupFilter. Он возвращает только булевую переменную. Возможно есть способ узнать количество фото в медиа группе?